# The keyboard shortcuts still link to /faq, not /tour

Tags: bug, keyboard-shortcuts

I've just remembered a way to get to the /tour page of a site, even if I have enough rep to review, easily! Just press <kbd>G</kbd> and then press <kbd>F</kbd>. This works because of the keyboard shortcuts<sup>1</sup>:

[image: gkeyboardshorcuts]

Now, pressing <kbd>F</kbd> helpfully takes me to... the FAQ? Huh? No, it doesn't take me to the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag on the meta site. Instead, it takes me to what *used* to be called the FAQ, which is now called the *tour*. It also links to /faq, which, fortunately, redirects to /tour. But you can't always depend on redirects, so.... **Can this please be changed so that it takes you to /tour instead of /faq?**

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>This view doesn't come up when you press <kbd>G</kbd> unless you've enabled auto-help, by pressing <kbd>H</kbd> (as <kbd>?</kbd> helpfully tells you).</sub>